# Redux Selector or Effect

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

Please help me to make the decision, regarding which technique to use.

I have a big list (up to million rows) that is kept in redux state.
Once user types in filter criterion, I want to apply filter and show filtered data (actually piece of it with react virtualized).

I do understand that ideally this is a use case for simple selector (or memoized reselect).

The problem that I see: filtering itself may take 2-3 seconds, thus, I have to use debounce. For debounce  i have to use middleware, because debouncing is asynchronous and impure.

Can effect (epic) take data from state and act as asynchronous selector? Or maybe there are some patterns for implementing debounce in selector?

Appreciate any advices.

Comment: For calculated data you should use reselect, since the filter takes long and blocks UI thread I would advice reselect and web worker

Comment: Thank you very much! The hint about web worker is perfect! This is the best advice so far

Comment: You could further optimise performance if you return paged results (assuming the filter shows data items and not graphs that need total data set). When you then cache those results you could get a pretty responsive app but it will use lots of memory so it's unlikely to work on phones.

Comment: Thanks, i'm using react-virtualized.
BTW, if you place your comments as an "Answer", i will mark it as a correct one.

Comment: If you have some working code you can answer your own question. I only gave a hint but you still need to implement it. I would be curious to see how you worked it out. If you have some trouble getting there I'm happy to help (maybe have a github with a sample app)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a big list (up to million rows) that is kept in redux state.

Really? You're doing blunder mistake. This will consume huge memory. And some browser may not respond them correctly.

So, I would suggest you to apply filtering from database results. On each filter being applied, the application will need to get the results from the database say upto 10, 20, 50, or 100.

With this sense, you can keep using redux or use memoized effect depending on your application logic/complexity. Both will work fine without worrying about debounce method.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately this is backendless SPA that gets data as ZIP file downloaded from Internet, and keeps it in state. No modifications to data is done - just displaying various selections. Thus, I need to choose between pure selector or effect placing filtered data back to store. Both cases are disgusting :(
Anyway, thanks for answering.